# Cypress - cost is not updated after an API call is intercepted

Tags: api, testing, cypress

The cypress test is for a coupon, after I enter a coupon then the price should be displayed accordingly.
When coupon is applied only 'PUT' method is made, the call is intercepted but the price is not updated on the page.

```
paymentPage = navigateAngular(IntakePaymentPage);
paymentPage.enterCouponCode('FREE');
cy.interceptSdk('PUT', 'engagement/*/cost', 'costFreeCoupon.json');
```

Comment: Do you get any errors? and can you post your entire code?

Comment: and could you do a GET to see if the PUT was actually a success?